# Synonym for asking for a discount just before closing a deal

Tags: phrases, translation, proverbs

In persian we have this phrase which translates to "the seasoning for the deal" or "نمک معامله" in the exact literature. Now, a realtor friend, as it is common in persian culture, would like to ask for a discount in a house's price at closing time. My question is if there is any equivalent phrase or word for the said phrase in English that effectively delivers the same sentiment.

An applicable example of a scenario with the same context would go as follows:

Seller: Why are asking for this additional discount at closing time?!

Buyer: It's the seasoning for the deal!

Comment: Anglophones in general aren't so interested in "bartering / haggling" as many other societies. In Britain, we invented the verb ***to gazump*** to cover the situation where at the last minute, a property seller asks the buyer for a higher price than originally agreed on.  Then we made the practice illegal.

Comment: I do not recommend this approach in the U.S. At closing all the paperwork is done and sitting on a table to be signed. Most sellers would take it poorly. What if the seller tries to up the price at closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be to *sweeten* the deal. A buyer could say - Can you sweeten the deal for me?

> *sweeten the deal*
>
> The definition of "sweeten the deal" is: to add something to an offer
> to make it sound more attractive. "sweeten the
> deal" means. to add something to an offer to make it sound more
> attractive.

from [www.ideomeanings.com](https://www.idiomeanings.com/sweeten-the-deal/)